# Why is Dotnet command hanging?

Tags: asp.net-core

Have a .net core service.  Can run the service perfectly fine from VS.  When I try to run dotnet publish to a folder and then run dotnet from the folder and the dll in the folder the command just hangs.  Same thing if i try to run from the dotnet run command from the project file. I do not believe this is because of my system as I can take the default service template and follow those steps and the service runs fine from the OOB template.  There are no errors in the console or the build.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of .NET SDK do you have on your OS?

Comment: .NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]   I am able to get the dotnet run command and dotnet dll name command to work with another solution on the machine just a fyi

Comment: Run as Administrator.